# Retrieve rows that are fully compatible with each other in an SQL database

Tags: sql, mysql, inner-join, relational-division

I have this simple structure in my database

```
CREATE TABLE species (
  _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE compatibility (
  _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  speciesA INTEGER,
  speciesB INTEGER,
  compatibility TINYINT NOT NULL
);
```

I want to point out that speciesA and speciesB are compound unique to prevent duplicated information. For example, if there would be only 5 species in my database, the compatibility table would look like this:

```
INSERT INTO species VALUES (1, 'EspecieA');
INSERT INTO species VALUES (2, 'EspecieB');
INSERT INTO species VALUES (3, 'EspecieC');
INSERT INTO species VALUES (4, 'EspecieD');
INSERT INTO species VALUES (5, 'EspecieD');

INSERT INTO compatibility VALUES (null, 1, 2, 1);
INSERT INTO compatibility VALUES (null, 1, 3, 1);
INSERT INTO compatibility VALUES (null, 1, 4, 1);
INSERT INTO compatibility VALUES (null, 1, 5, 0);
INSERT INTO compatibility VALUES (null, 2, 3, 1);
INSERT INTO compatibility VALUES (null, 2, 4, 1);
INSERT INTO compatibility VALUES (null, 2, 5, 0);
INSERT INTO compatibility VALUES (null, 3, 4, 1);
INSERT INTO compatibility VALUES (null, 3, 5, 1);
INSERT INTO compatibility VALUES (null, 4, 5, 1);
```

I need to write a query that from a given list of species returns a list of species that are fully compatible with each other, meaning all species in the result list must be compatible with all the species in the list provided. Provided species must not be in the result list.

I have tried the following query, but it only returns species that are compatible with at least one of the provided species:

```
SELECT id, name
FROM species s
WHERE s.id NOT IN (
    SELECT IF(speciesA NOT IN (1,2,3), speciesA, speciesB) AS specie
    FROM compatibility 
    WHERE (speciesA IN (1,2,3)
    AND compatible IN (0)) OR (speciesB IN (1,2,3)
    AND compatible IN (0))
)
AND s.id NOT IN (1,2,3);
```

How can I modify this query to obtain the list of species that are fully compatible with each other?

For the query above the expected result should be a list of species that only contains species 4. Species 1, 2, 3 are excluded as are in the list provided, and 5 should be excluded cause is not compatible with species 1 and 2.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please can you clarify with some examples?  eg in your 3 species example, is it that an input of species 1 should result in output of species 3 only, input of species 2 should result in output of species 3 only, but input of species 3 should output species 1 and 2?  (Am I reading your compatiblity table correctly?)

Comment: What is the difference between a row with compatible = 0 compared to the absence of this row?

Comment: I've added some more details to the question.
In the database there will be no absence, all the compatibility possibilities will be added to the db. Would it be easier if they don't exist?

Comment: Thanks - please see answer below, the first proposed solution I think is what you need.  Again, not sure of the purpose of your 'compatibility' column, if two species are not compatible, wouldn't you just not have an entry for that pair in the compatibility table?

Comment: Error_ **Column '_id' cannot be null**.

Comment: @jarlh, itś an autoincrement but indexes are not set. I wanted to simplify the question. I'll add the species insert as well so it's easier to reproduce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will only include species that are explicitly linked with compatibility = 1 (ie assumes by default that species are not compatible)

```
SELECT s._id, s.name
FROM species s
INNER JOIN compatibility c ON
    (s._id = c.speciesA AND c.speciesB IN (1, 2))
    OR (s._id = c.speciesB AND c.speciesA IN (1, 2))
WHERE c.compatibility = 1
AND s._id NOT IN (1, 2)
```

This will include all species except those that are explicitly linked with compatibility = 0 (ie assumes by default that species are compatible)

```
SELECT s._id, s.name
FROM species s
LEFT JOIN compatibility c ON
    ((s._id = c.speciesA AND c.speciesB IN (1, 2))
    OR (s._id = c.speciesB AND c.speciesA IN (1, 2)))
    AND c.compatibility = 0
WHERE c._id IS NULL
AND s._id NOT IN (1, 2)
```

Whichever of these better fits your logic, I would also recommend that to optimise query performance you add indices on the `compatibility.speciesA` and `compatibility.speciesB` columns.

Comment: The LEFT query looks fine. I'll test it and come back to you. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

We can solve the question with filtering and aggregation.

```
select spec
from (
    select 
        case when speciesA in (1, 2, 3) then speciesA else speciesB end as ref,
        case when speciesA in (1, 2, 3) then speciesB else speciesA end as spec
    from compatibility c
) c
where ref in (1, 2, 3)
group by spec
having count(*) = 3
```

The subquery puts the reference species (`ref`) and the compatible species (`spec`) in two different columns. We can then filter on the three reference species that you are interested in, group by the compatible species, and finally retain groups that match entirely with a `having` clause.

If you wanted the name of the species as well, we can `join`:

```
select c.spec, s.name
from (
    select 
        case when speciesA in (1, 2, 3) then speciesA else speciesB end as ref,
        case when speciesA in (1, 2, 3) then speciesB else speciesA end as spec
    from compatibility c
) c
inner join species s on s._id = c.spec
where c.ref in (1, 2, 3)
group by c.spec
having count(*) = 3
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bD7vRYwt)**